# Associate a vlan in Softlayer with java

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am implementing Associate a Vlan after purchasing Vyatta. 
What Softlayer API should be used to implement it ? If you provide a sample java code or API guide, it will be appreciated.

Thank you

[image: reference image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method can help you to use associate a VLAN to a gateway:

[SoftLayer_Network_Gateway_Vlan::createObject](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Gateway_Vlan/createObject)

Below is a Rest example:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Gateway_Vlan/createObject

Method: POST

Json payload:

{
  "parameters": [
    {
      "bypassFlag": false,
      "networkGatewayId": 172323,
      "networkVlanId": 561712
    }
  ]
}
```

Also, to get all VLANs that can become inside VLANs on this gateway, please see:

[SoftLayer_Network_Gateway::getPossibleInsideVlans](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Gateway/getPossibleInsideVlans)

Example:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Gateway/[gateway_id]/getPossibleInsideVlans?objectMask=mask[primaryRouter]
Method: GET
```

I hope it help you